# Bootstrap Gallery Class Causing background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed this http://codepen.io/redfrost/pen/dbrgk codepen working gallery snippet to the tee . Everything works as far as functionality but there is a background coming from a bootstrap class that makes the gallery wider than expected. The arrows according to the snippet should be contained within the image div itself.

I have deleted both style sheets just to see if the background would go away and it did not. It is a bootstrap class issue.

Here is the image of the issue http://postimg.org/image/mmdbsl6sp/full/

I think the class causing the issue is class="carousel-inner"

Here is the markup I have for the gallery:

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="bannerImage">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/960x405" alt=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="caption row-fluid">
                <div class="span4"><h3>Picture 1</h3>

                </div>                  
                <div class="span8"><p>Picture 1 details</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 

        <div class="item">
            <div class="bannerImage">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/960x405" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="caption row-fluid">
                <div class="span4"><h3>Picture 2</h3>
                </div>                  
                <div class="span8"><p>Picture 2 details</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /Slide2 -->             

        <div class="item">
            <div class="bannerImage">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/960x405" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="caption row-fluid">
                <div class="span4"><h3>Picture 3</h3>

                </div>                  
                <div class="span8"><p>Picture 3 details</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /Slide2 -->                      

    </div>

    <div class="control-box">                            
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
    </div><!-- /.control-box -->   

</div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.span12 -->          
</div><!-- /.row --> 
</div><!-- /.container -->

@stop
```

Here is the css:

```css
div { word-break: break-all; }

img { 
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease; 
}

a:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE7 */
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Container */

/* Page Header */
.page-header {
    background: #fbf4e0;
    margin: -30px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
    color: #a83b3b;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page-header h3 {
    line-height: 0.88rem;
    color: #a83b3b;
}

/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.caption .span4, .caption .span8 {
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.caption .span4 {
    border-right: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
}

.caption h3 {
    color: #a83b3b;
    line-height: 2rem;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.caption p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    color: #a83b3b;
}

.btn.btn-mini {
    background: #a83b3b;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    color: #fbf4e0;
    font-size: 0.63rem;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.carousel-control {
    top: 33%;
    zoom: 7;
    color: #ff3333;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.69rem;
}

.footer, .footer a {
    color: #fff;
}

p.right  { 
    float: right; 
}

body:after{content:"less than 320px";font-size:1rem;font-weight:bold;position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:hsla(1,60%,40%,0.7);color:#fff;height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0;left:0}@media only screen and (min-width:320px){body:after{content:"320 to 480px";background-color:hsla(90,60%,40%,0.7);height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0}}@media only screen and (min-width:480px){body:after{content:"480 to 768px";background-color:hsla(180,60%,40%,0.7);height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0}}@media only screen and (min-width:768px){body:after{content:"768 to 980px";background-color:hsla(270,60%,40%,0.7);height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0}}@media only screen and (min-width:980px){body:after{content:"980 to 1024px";background-color:hsla(300,60%,40%,0.7);height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0}}@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){body:after{content:"1024 and up";background-color:hsla(360,60%,40%,0.7);height:20px;padding-top:0;margin-left:0}}

::selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0; }
::-moz-selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; }

a, a:focus, a:active, a:hover, object, embed { outline: none; }
:-moz-any-link:focus { outline: none; }
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap is that codepen using ?

Comment: @lagbox I just read the footer of the codepen and the link goes to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ which is no longer supported.

Comment: and what version are you using ?

Comment: @lagbox The latest v3.

Comment: you may want to double check this http://getbootstrap.com/migration/  just to see if the version may be the issue

Comment: @lagbox Thanks. I will check the link and see what classes I need to change in the carousel.

Comment: @lagbox I realized the problem was class=""caption" was supposed to be class="carousel-caption". However, I decided to go with a cleaner source with less css here http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/bin/output.php